# How do I set a CSS class on a table row based on a property of an ATK node attribute in ATK-Framework?

Tags: php, frameworks

I have an [ATK-Framework](http://www.atk-framework.com/) which I'm inheriting from a previous (departed) developer, and I'm finding the documentation to be sparse and poorly structured.

We have a subscription system where customer register an account, and then there can be multiple subscriptions on that account. The classes for accounts and subscriptions inherit from atkNode.

I want to be able to highlight a row in a table of subscriptions so that it is easier to see, at a glance, when a particular subscription has expired. The expiry date of the subscription is already a property of that node.

I can easily find the code where the node is created in the framework's modules - but try as hard as I can, I can't find any corresponding HTML template to display this information, and so can't find anyway to add in the required logic to highlight these rows.

--
Update:

After some more clicking around, I've found the templates - they're in the main ATK framework directory (including the custom templates that my predecessor has created).

They appear to be smarty-like templates, so modifying/extending them shouldn't be too hard.

--

So, I found the following in the template:

```
{foreach from=$rows item=row}
    <tr id="{$row.id}" class="row{if $row.rownum % 2 == 0 }1{else}2{/if}" {if $row.background!=""}style="background-color:{$row.background}" {/if}
          onmouseover="highlightrow(this, '{$row.highlight}')"
          onmouseout="resetrow(this)"
          onclick="selectrow(this, '{$listid}', {$row.rownum})">
        {section name=colloop loop=$row.cols}
            <{if $row.type == "subtotal"}th{else}td{/if}
                  class="{if $smarty.section.colloop.index===0}recordListTdFirst{else}recordListTd{/if}{if $row.cols[colloop].type == "data"} clickable{/if}"
                  valign="{$vorientation}"  {if isset($row.cols[colloop].htmlattributes)}{$row.cols[colloop].htmlattributes}{/if}
                  {if $row.cols[colloop].type == "data"} onclick="rl_try('{$listid}', event, {$row.rownum}, ['select', 'edit', 'view'], false);"{/if}>
                {if $row.cols[colloop].content != ""}{$row.cols[colloop].content}{else}&nbsp;{/if}
            </{if $row.type == "subtotal"}th{else}td{/if}>
        {/section}
    </tr>
{/foreach}
```

I'm guessing that $row and $cols are set by the class...

There's a couple of problems - this recordlist.tpl is a generic template. This means that I can't just jam a check for the expiry date at this point.

**Is there a way to override this template for one specific node/recordset?**

Comment: I can't see it either. BTW, What is an ATK node? Your question might not be so clear. It sounds like you are not telling us an important piece of info - what technology you are using.

Comment: `ATK Code Generator is a robust application designed to assist PHP developers in generating web applications relatively fast without any coding.` *sadface*

Comment: throwing 200 reputation points for such "unclear" question is really a waste! I really think that you need to edit your qustions, add what have you tried so far, some code...

Comment: Post the HTML snippet including the table and all related elements that may help create a CSS rule.

Comment: I 'threw' the bounty at it because I wanted an answer. I acknowledge that the question is not exactly clear, but since posting the bounty I've had two suggestions on how to make the question better - therefore making it more likely I'll get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the ATK zip and as you said, it appears to just be smarty (atk/ui/smarty), if you can throw the template tag {debug} into your template anywhere you *should* get a smarty debug window, in which you can see how the arrays/objects have been assigned/structured in the smarty template engine.

If the property has been assiend to the row focus on {$row.X} if the property is against the column focus on {$row.cols[colloop].X}, if the date is a unix timestamp you should be able to do

```
class="row{if $row.rownum % 2 == 0 }1{else}2{/if}{if $row.timestamp_var < $smarty.now} your_class_name{/if}"
```

for a simple date comparison.

Comment: Sorry, your edit was after my post. Is the expiration value uniquely named? if so you could check for it's existance before the date comparison, even though it's a generic template. I'm answering this from an experience with smarty only point of view :)